# Child components componentDidMount() should call different methods depends on parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  class Parent1 extends Component {
    render() {
                return (
                    <Child />
                );
            }
    }
        
  class Parent2 extends Component {
    render() {
            return (
                <Child />
            );
         }
  }

class Child extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // If child component is called from Parent1 component then
        //then It should  getAction1()
        
        // If child component is called from Parent2 component then
        //then It should call getAction2()
    }
    
    render() {
        return(
        //// some jsx code
        );
    }
}
```

In the Child component, componentDidMount() should call different methods depends on calling Parent component. How will I achieve this? Is it possible to achieve this without if else conditions?

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be to pass your function as a prop on `Child`.

```
class Parent1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Child getAction={getAction1}/>
    );
  }
}
        
class Parent2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Child getAction={getAction2}/>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
  // this.props.getAction will be getAction1 or getAction2
  // depending on which was passed
    this.props.getAction() 
  }
    
  render() {
    return(
    //// some jsx code
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution can be sending a prop from parent to child

```
class Parent1 extends Component {
     render() {
            return (
                <Child functionP1={parent1Func}/>
            );
        }
}
class Parent2 extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Child functionP2={parent2Func}/>
        );
     }
}

class Child extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.functionP2();
    }

render() {
    return(
    //// some jsx code
    );
}
}
```

The best practice is to pass the parent-specific function data from parent to child.
but still, if you want to write the function calls in the child component itself,then you can just declare a variable and pass it as a prop:

```
 class Parent1 extends Component {
     render() {
            return (
                <Child checkParent={parentOne}/>
            );
        }
}

 class Parent2 extends Component {
     render() {
            return (
                <Child checkParent={parentTwo}/>
            );
        }
}

class Child extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
     // check for value of this.props.checkParent and
    // execute functions accordingly
    }
}
```